# AngularJs URL changes with different parameters but view remains same. It only changes on refresh. How to render page on each parameter change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, http

Inside the controller I do a AJAX call and render data. Basically I have different inbox types which I want to render through passing parameter from URL to my API through a http post call inside the Controller. In the navigation as:  
Similarly I pass other parameters to the url on different inbox types.

When I click on Recent URL : /list/&type=recent and content is rendered
When I click on Starred URL : /list/&type=starred but content is not rendered. I have to manually refresh the page to view the new content.

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller('SmsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$http', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, transformRequestAsFormPost) {

    $scope.method = $stateParams.inboxType;

    console.log("Inbox Type : "+ $stateParams.inboxType );

    $http.post('tpl/processors/process-list.php', {method : $scope.method})
    .then(function(response) {

        console.log(response.data);  
        $scope.smses = response.data;
        console.log($scope.smses);

      }
    }, function(x) {
      $scope.authError = 'Server Error';
    });
    console.log("Inbox Type after HTTP Call : "+ $stateParams.inboxType );

  });
}]);
```

My navigation :

```
<a ui-sref="app.mail.list({inboxType: '&type=recent'})">

<a ui-sref="app.mail.list({inboxType: '&type=reminders'})">


<a ui-sref="app.mail.list({inboxType: '&type=favourites'})">
```

I m stuck here. Please help as I am new to Angular JS.

Comment: Can you show your full code, an online demo is better to understand. What messages you are getting in your console?

Comment: In the console log, sms json object is received. My SMS List is generating and working fine. My question is, page data doesn't refresh when I click on reminders and favourites while url changes.

Comment: You want your `$stateParams.inboxType` to be in `'&type=recent'` or `'recent'` format?

Comment: I want '&type=recent'. That I m getting perfect. My list is also generated according to my expectations. My issue is navigation. While navigating to some other link, the url changes but there is no change in html. When I refresh the page manually, it loads data.